# PDF to Word Converter

Tags: gratis, pdf, document-converter, microsoft-word

I'm looking for a software, which is able to convert a pdf document into a docx file. 
I know there is Adobe Acrobat Professional which does a good job concerning this. The drawback is that it costs money. 
I want a software which can do this for free.

Requirements:

- free of charge
- output either doc or docx
- should be able to handle pictures, tables and text in the document
- should convert documents with 15 and more pages in one run
- Windows or Linux

Comment: Well, I know that Foxit Phantom is able to do that (http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Security/convert-export.php) But it's not free therefore I cannot post it as an answer. However, you can use the trial maybe?

Comment: There are plenty of SaaS options... this is [one of many](http://www.zamzar.com/)

Comment: Word 2013 will do this. Just open the PDF from within Word. I don't include it as an answer because Word is not free.

Comment: You want text to remain selectable/searchable I guess? Many converters just include everything as unmodifiable images, you should say that you don't want that.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/240011/how-to-convert-pdf-file-to-an-odt-file. Nothing there that seems to support tables though.

Comment: @Irgendw Pointer: If an answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future.

Comment: Do you find answer to this question?

Answer (score 5):

[Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org) is completely free office suite that can open and edit pdf files.

You can run it on Windows and Linux (also, Mac OS X)

Comment: Adding more details would be great ;)

Comment: You can edit text boxes in LibreOffice Draw, but you can't convert the PDF files to anything but image files.

Comment: LibreOffice Draw loads each page as a drawing and tables are not really supported. Each cell is converted to a separate text field, so you can't navigate between cells using tab and shift-tab. Still +1 since I guess that a pdf never stores the relation between text in different cells, so I don't believe that any existing software can recognize a table in a pdf file as such.

Comment: Have to take back my last sentence since Easy Converter (see Nick Wilde's answer) does seem to be good at recognizing tables, too.

Comment: No it can't. That is, it can't open and edit PDFs as documents.

Answer (score 4):

There are two free web apps that do this quite well:

- [SmallPDF](https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-word)
- [Sejda](https://www.sejda.com/pdf-to-word)

In particular, Sejda works for up to 200 pages.

Comment: SmallPDF worked really well for me, all completely free.

Comment: SmallPDF didn't work for me, it just converts the PDF to a image stored in a Word file. Useless.

Comment: Sedja worked ok, but the document layout in the converted Word file could have been better.

Answer (score 3):

[Easy Converter](http://www.pdfonline.com/easyconverter/).

It has a (free) [online mode](http://www.pdfonline.com/pdf-to-word-converter/) or the desktop (Windows) app for $20 (USD) - with a free trial.

I have only used the online version however it was very accurate. and now to go over your specific requirements one by one:

- *free of charge*: Online: **Yes**, Desktop: **No**: Free Trial available - $20 for full version.
- *output either doc or docx*: **No**; exports as RTF; that is openable in pretty much any version of word however.
- *should be able to handle pictures, tables and text in the document* yeah pretty well though some users have found table export to be unreliable.
- *should convert documents with 15 and more pages in one run*: Trial version only supports first **three** pages and adds an advertising page at the end.
- *Windows or Linux*: Windows

Comment: not able to handle tables well,i tried :|

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Nickolai you may use LibreOffice for  PDF to Word conversion that works pretty well for reasonably simple PDF files.

LibreOffice has some utilities like **convert** that allow you to run it headless from the command line in Linux, Windows and MAC so you can do the conversions in the background.

Answer (score 1):

To open a PDF in LibreOffice Writer, you need to choose "PDF - Portable Document Format (Writer)" in the File Open dialog:

[image: image description]

Then you can save it in whatever format you wish (to odt, to doc, to docx).

Answer (score 1):

Machine-readable PDF files can actually be opened in the current MS Word program. You just need to open the PDF using MS Word. A pop-up warning will appear and once you've confirmed this, it will open as a Word file where you can edit the content like a .doc file and save as PDF again once done.
[image: Word processor warning]

However, this works only to machine-readable files. Meaning, if your PDF is a scanned file, the computer will only recognize your PDF as an image-only file and will only open it as an image on the word processor.

If you don't have MS Word or if you have a scanned PDF file with you, we suggest you try the software we are developing which is [DeftPDF online](https://deftpdf.com/). It has tools that can answer your requirements - can convert PDF to doc file, without limitations, can be used in any platform. For scanned files, you can use the OCR tool within the web-based app to convert the PDF into a machine-readable file. This converter tool (PDF to DOC or the OCR tool) is web-based though and needs to be operated online through your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe this is a seven year old question and that no one has yet mentioned the undisputed king of converters (and viewers), [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/).

From the [Faq](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html):

> What formats does calibre support conversion to/from?
>
> calibre supports the conversion of many input formats to many output
> formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to
> every output format.
>
> ***Input*** Formats: AZW, AZW3, AZW4, CBZ, CBR, CB7, CBC, CHM, DJVU, DOCX,
> EPUB, FB2, FBZ, HTML, HTMLZ, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, ***PDF***, PRC, PDB, PML,
> RB, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ
>
> ***Output*** Formats: AZW3, EPUB, ***DOCX***, FB2, HTMLZ, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI,
> PDB, PMLZ, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ, ZIP

Calibre has been around [since 2006](https://calibre-ebook.com/about#history), is open-source, stable, widely used ([currently](https://calibre-ebook.com/dynamic/calibre-usage)
(Active installs: 3,389,907 (those that have started calibre at least once in the last 60 days)),  and well supported, inluding a [tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/calibre) on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), and runs on Linux, Windows, Android, iOSiOS andmacOS.

Check out the [demo](https://calibre-ebook.com/demo)

[image]