# PDF to DOC or ODT converter

Tags: pdf, document-converter

I need PDF to DOC converter with following features:

- (most important) convert text without inserting additional linebreaks and spaces (so I could make significant changes in the doc file later)
- keep properly formatted footnotes;
- if possible, keep also picture captions.

The PDF file has text layer, so no OCR is needed, but can have complex formatting, like verses of different kind.

What I already tried:

- demo version of Nitro PDF. Maybe I didn't found the best combination of options, but it was a mess: double or triple spaces, linebreaks in the middle of a paragraph, footnotes in the middle of the page...
- I read answer to this [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/pdf-to-word-converter) and tried to open my pdf with Libre Office. By default it opens in Liber Office Draw, with each line as separate object and no option to flexible editing of the text.
- Easy PDF Online, mentioned in the same question, has the same problem, as Nitro PDF (inserted spaces, linebreaks, picture captions disappeared).

I see that there possibly no good free solution, so I'm looking at different paid software too. I'm working on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Do you have Word 2013 by any chance? It is capable of opening PDF files and converting them to doc(x). (Note though that it sometimes does its job quite fine and sometimes destroys the layout. It highly depends on your document.)

Comment: @ComFreek I have trial version of Office 365 pre-installed on my notebook. Will it do this conversion too, or is ir only for Word 2013? (I cannot check it myself because I don't plan to activate this trial until I really will need it)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. If the trial is equivalent to a full version of Office 365 (for a limited time period), you should actually be able to open PDF files with Word since Office 365 = the latest office as far as I know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDF to Word Converter](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/pdf-to-word-converter)

Answer (score 3):

You can give a shot to [Adobe Acrobat Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro.html):

- non-free
- Windows
- can export PDF to DOC or DOCX:

[image]

Issues:

- figure captions and footnotes are kept but converted into normal text
- LaTeX formulas often have trouble getting properly converted

But it rarely inserts additional linebreaks and spaces.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Can I get to use adobe pro version for few days?

Comment: @kvk30 there's a 7-day trial I believe

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82882/need-a-software-for-pdf-to-doc-converter, if you find any useful solution, please post here. :)