# Need a software for PDF to DOC converter

Tags: pdf, document-converter, pdf-editor

I'm looking for a software, which is able to convert a pdf document into a doc file. I know there is Adobe Acrobat Professional which does a good job concerning this. The drawback is that it costs for monthly basis. I want a software which I can rent for few days too.

Requirements:

1. Free/rent it for few days.
2. output either doc or docx.
3. should be able
   to handle pictures, tables and text in the document.
4. should convert    documents with 800 and more pages.
5. Omit referred language

Example:
My document contains Hindi and English, In which I need to omit Hindi.

Comment: `it costs for monthly basis` this is fundamentally "renting" it. You would pay for a single month and stop subscription, thus fitting your first point.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Alejandro, but I need for 2-3 days only. :)

Comment: @Alejandro, I tried Acrobat Pro for a while, was mostly happy to pay-per-month, then when I wanted to qui, I got hit with an "early termination" fee (which I could have known about had I read The Agreement). As far as I can see, Adobe has no pricing model for _casually_ or _intermittently_ using their products.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe Acrobat Professional has a trial version that lasts 7 days.

https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/free-trial-download.html:

> The trial period begins on the day you sign up and continues for 7 consecutive days. On the 8th day, payment will be collected unless you cancel before the end of your trial period. If you cancel, you can still use Acrobat to view PDFs, comment and fill forms. To access all the full set of Acrobat features again, you will need to subscribe to Acrobat Pro DC.

Disclaimer: I'm an Adobe employee.